# Python: How does one create a pie chart from a database?

Tags: python, sqlite, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to build a pie chart from my database.

The python GUI app I'm building is done with tKinter
Currently I'm using sqlite3 for the database, and I've been told to use matplotlib as the table generator.

This app I'm making is for a Savings System

This is the code I'm using to input data into the database

```
def Submit():
    #Creating or connecting to a Database
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Balance.db")

    #create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()

    c.execute("INSERT INTO Log VALUES (:value, :type, :tag)",
            {
                'value': value.get(),
                'type': var.get(),
                'tag': tag.get()
            })

    #commit changes
    conn.commit()

    #close connection
    conn.close()


    #clear the text boxes to allow for new input
    value.delete(0, END)
    #cbv is not included in this since cbv is checkbox data
    tag.delete(0,END)

Submit_Button = Button(root, text = "Add to Logs", command = Submit)
Submit_Button.grid(row=9, column = 0)
```

However, what I want to be able to do is from this log, pull out those three variables, the value, type, and tag to create a pie chart representing type (expenses), value (from the total of expenses combined) and tag (how I want to split the cuts in the pies)

Unfortunately, I don't know how to pull out singular Variables from the database.

Can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: if the database issue was solved, would you still need help with plotting?

Comment: The database is fine, I just don't understand how one would take out data from this log, like all data in "tag" specifically. I understand how to take all data out, but I can't figure out how to do specifics

Comment: *"Unfortunately, I don't know how to pull out singular Variables from the database."* So if your question about that or about how to construct a pie chart?

Comment: Hvae you tried `mathplotlib`

Comment: I can do a pie chart, I just don't know how to pull the variables out of the log. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the snippet if you are looking for something like this.

You can store `value,type and tag` values in variable and then use it to insert into database and also for calling in matplotlib

[image: matplotlib]

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
root=tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x100")

def Submit():
    value=value_entry.get()
    types=type_entry.get()
    tags=tags_entry.get()
    conn = sqlite3.connect("Balance.db")
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO Log VALUES (:value, :type, :tag)",
            {
                'value': value,
                'type': types,
                'tag': tags
            })
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
    label=["value","type","tag"]
    data=[value,types,tags]
    fig = plt.figure(figsize =(5, 5)) 
    plt.pie(data, labels = label,autopct='%1.2f%%')
    plt.show()
    #clear the text boxes to allow for new input
    values.set("")
    typess.set("")
    tagss.set("")

values=tk.IntVar() 
typess=tk.IntVar()
tagss=tk.IntVar()

value_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Value')
value_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = values)
type_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Type')
type_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = typess)
tags_label = tk.Label(root, text = 'Tags')
tags_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable = tagss) 
Submit_Button = tk.Button(root, text = "Add to Logs", command = Submit)

value_label.grid(row=0,column=0) 
value_entry.grid(row=0,column=1) 
type_label.grid(row=1,column=0) 
type_entry.grid(row=1,column=1)
tags_label.grid(row=2,column=0) 
tags_entry.grid(row=2,column=1) 
Submit_Button.grid(row=3, column = 1)
   
root.mainloop()
```

**Note** - If you dont want data in percentage , you can remove `autopct='%1.2f%%'`

Comment: Thanks! This works! How would I go about selecting specific types, so Tag, is the name of all the sections of the pie, "type" with value of "Expense", and then Value as the percentage of a whole?

Like add all values of "Value" that are type = "Expense", and then make each value with different tags different sections of pie, one piece for each tag,?

Comment: @JulianMo sorry I am unable to get you. Can you please explain **selecting specific types, so Tag, is the name of all the sections of the pie, "type" with value of "Expense"**

Comment: So like values of "Value" that are type = "Expense", and then make each value with different tags different sections of pie, one piece for each tag,? Does that kind of explain it? Sorry if this is  bit confusing

Comment: Basically your type is string which would contain **Expense** and some other types,your value is **expense value** what is tag then?

Comment: Tag is like, the custom label you can add to sort your transaction in banking apps, and from there be able to group all values with tag under a certain part of the chart?

Comment: @JulianMo I am so sorry. I may not be able to help you further regarding your next requirement as i am unclear of it. If you find my answer helpful you can accept it as an answer

Comment: Fair enough, I thank you for your help anyway. This has been very useful.